# TensorFlow Object Detection API: specifying multiple data_augmentation_options

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, data-augmentation

I'm wondering if there's any difference between specifying the data augmentations like this:

```
data_augmentation_options {
  random_horizontal_flip {
  }
}
data_augmentation_options {
  ssd_random_crop {
  }
}
```

Or like this:

```
data_augmentation_options {
  random_horizontal_flip {
  }
  ssd_random_crop {
  }
}
```

In the object detection pipeline file?

All the samples in the models repo use the first format, but the second format is accepted as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only correct format is the first one.

While the second one will not break the pipeline, it will only take the first specified option.
You can verify this yourself by inspecting the created pipeline.config in model_dir.
The reason for that is that `data_augmentation_options` is of type `PreprocessingStep` which consists of a `oneof preprocessing_step`. Note the `oneof`.

On the other hand, `data_augmentation_options` is `repeated`, thus you can specify

```
data_augmentation_options {
  augmentation_option_1 {
  }
}
data_augmentation_options {
  augmentation_option_2 {
  }
}
...
```

and so on, as many as you like.